# Creating dictionary that map type T as key to instance of type T

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary between type and instance of that type.
For example for the dictionary MyTypeDictionary :

```
Dictionary<Type,InstanceOfType> MyTypeDictionary = new  Dictionary<Type,InstanceOfType>();                        
MyTypeDictionary.Add(typeof(int),4);  
MyTypeDictionary.Add(typeof(string),"hello world");  
MyTypeDictionary.Add(typeof(DateTime),Datetime.Now); 
int MyInt = MyTypeDictionary[typeof(int)];
```

What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: You can't do this with the standard `Dictionary` class, but you can create your own class that contains a private `Dictionary<Type, object>` field along with a couple generic methods for getting and setting typed values: `public void Add<T>(T value)` and `public T Get<T>()`.

Comment: Very hard to guess why you would write code like this.  It makes very little sense to allow only a single dictionary entry per type.  Look at the ExpandoObject class instead.

Comment: I want to create a dictionary of predicates by type that the input is the type (the key itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

I create a new class that wrap the dictionary:

```
public class NewDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<Type, object> dic = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public void Add<T>(T obj)
    {
        dic[typeof(T)] = obj;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        if (IsTypeExists(typeof(T)) == false)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)dic[typeof(T)];
    }

    public bool IsTypeExists(Type t)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(t) == false)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

By using this class I can use the dictionary to map the type to instance.
I can use it like this:

```
        NewDictionary myCollection = new NewDictionary();
        myCollection.Add<int>(4);
        myCollection.Add<string>("Hello world");
        myCollection.Add<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);
```

And get the instance by 'get' by using type:

```
        int number = myCollection.Get<int>();
        string text = myCollection.Get<string>();
        DateTime date = myCollection.Get<DateTime>();
```