# Dynamic C++ Map <String, Primitives (int, double, string, or array)>

Tags: c++, dynamic, dictionary

My apologies in advance, but I can't find this one.

In C++ I want a have a map.  This map will consist of `<string, Object>`; where the objects are added dynamical from an XML document during runtime.  The Object will either be a int, double, string, or array of ints, doubles, or string.  The key is guaranteed to be unique.  However, I need a way to dynamically declare this using a map.

Is this perhaps an instance when I should be using a template for the data part?

I can't use a large lib such as boost to achieve this, since this should be a light wight program.
(Ref: [Use boost C++ libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682355/use-boost-c-libraries))

This is similar to what im trying to achieve.  Where the user specified the primitive type: (Ref: [Creating dictionary that map type T as key to instance of type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803613/creating-dictionary-that-map-type-t-as-key-to-instance-of-type-t))

```
std::map <std::string, ????> Values;
```

**Edit:**
So if I can't use boost, could I achieve this using a template?

In boost I am dong this:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string> datum;
std::map<std::string, datum> Parms;
```

Then I later adding values during run-time (from XML, where each element has an attribute with the specified type)

```
Parms["a"] = 10; // int
Parms["b"] = 102.2039; // double
Parms["c"] = 6.6667e-07; // another double
Parms["d"] = "Hello world"; // std::string
```

The problem is when I do this:

```
datum v1 = obj.get("c");  // need double, not datum
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a single map that holds different value types, or separate maps depending on type?

Comment: I don't think [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) should be that _heavy_. It's header only IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed it is, and so is `boost::variant`. Actually the vast majority of Boost is header-only. @OP: C++ developers should generally try hard to be able to use Boost. No sense re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: merlin2011 to answer your question, I am attempting to make a map which holds different value types.

Comment: The project requires no major dependencies, else wise I would just include boost.  Unfortunately, lots of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider embedding your primitive type in a struct. You can define a base class from which the different structs are derived. You probably need to save the type as well into the struct, but I left it out for simplicity.

If you really need the primitive types, ignore my answer and go for Boost.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct BaseObject {};

struct ObjectInt : public BaseObject
{
  int a;
};

struct ObjectString : public BaseObject
{
  std::string a;
};

int main()
{
  BaseObject *oi, *os;
  oi = new ObjectInt;
  os = new ObjectString;
  std::map<std::string, BaseObject *> objectMap;

  objectMap["oi"] = oi;
  objectMap["os"] = os;

  delete oi;
  delete os;

  return 0;
}
```